# kubectl exec failed with "container <command> is not valid for pod <pod_name>"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am working with Minikube and I have alpine pod with one container.
When I run:
`kubectl exec -it -v=6 alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc /bin/sh`

I receive a shell and I can run any command (`ifconfig`, etc.) inside it.

But when I tried to run `sh` with `-c` it failed:

```
root:~# kubectl exec -it -v=6 alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc /bin/sh -c 'ifconfig'
I0722 05:45:25.091111   80392 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /home/root/.kube/config
I0722 05:45:25.111876   80392 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.190.143:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc 200 OK in 16 milliseconds
I0722 05:45:25.232564   80392 round_trippers.go:405] POST https://192.168.190.143:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc/exec?command=%2Fbin%2Fsh&container=ifconfig&container=ifconfig&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true 400 Bad Request in 13 milliseconds
                                                                     I0722 05:45:25.232921   80392 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "container ifconfig is not valid for pod alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
}]
F0722 05:45:25.233095   80392 helpers.go:119] Error from server (BadRequest): container ifconfig is not valid for pod alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

kubectl interprets the `-c` flag not as a flag for `ifconfig`, but as a flag for the `kubectl exec` command itself -- which specifies the exact container of a Pod in which the command should be executed; this is also the reason that `kubectl` looks for a *container* named "ifconfig" in your Pod. See [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) for more information.

Instead, use `--` to denote flags that should not be interpreted by `kubectl exec` any more but instead be passed to the invoked command (`ifconfig`, in this case) as-is:

```
$ kubectl exec -it -v=6 alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc -- /bin/sh -c 'ifconfig'
```

Also note that in this case, you do not really need to invoke ifconfig from a shell; you could also just directly call `ifconfig` without using `/bin/sh`:

```
$ kubectl exec -it -v=6 alpinec1-7c65db48b4-v2gpc -- ifconfig
```

Comment: it seems kubectl exec requires container name (irrespective of we specified or not) . Isnt there a way to just connect the pod ( and not the container) ?

Comment: No -- a Pod is just a logical group of containers, so you _always_ connect to a container within the Pod. In general, you always need to specify which container in your Pod you want to connect to (using `-c`), *except* your Pod consists of only one container (in which case there's not really a choice, anyway).

Comment: it makes sense as the the containers and the pod share the same namespace ,ip address.. hopefully , logially , it wont make any difference connecting to container vs connecting to pod ?